# Google Fusion Map Javascript Drop-Down Menu Not Working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I have implemented a javascript menu allowing users to change to different map views using the Google Fusion Table overlays. Unfortunately, my dropdown menus don't work separately or together. For example, someone wants to see ports in "Middle East" Region only or someone wants to see ports in "Indian Sub-Continent" Region AND "ICD" Type of port.

Second problem seems to be the markers not showing up as identified in Fusion Table. They have different colors for "Shipping" and "ICD" for "Type" of port.

This is my work so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Fusion Map</title>

    <style>
        body {margin:0 auto; width:960px;}
        #map_div {height:550px; width:100%; margin-top:50px;}
    </style>

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        var tableid = 1102368;
        var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(1102368);

        function initialize() {
        var ports = new google.maps.LatLng(35.173808, 37.236325);
        var myOptions = {
            center: ports,
            zoom: 3,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'),
            myOptions);
                layer.setMap(map);
        }

        function refreshFusion() {
            var qry = "SELECT PortName, 'Region' FROM " + tableid;
            var region = document.getElementById('ddRegion').value;
            var type = document.getElementById('ddType').value;
            var filters = [];
            if(type != '') {
                filters.push("'Type' CONTAINS '" + type + "'");
            }
            if(type != '') {
                filters.push("'Region' CONTAINS '" + region + "'");
            }
            if(filters.lenght > 0) {
                qry += " WHERE " + filters.join(" AND ");
            }
            layer.setQuery(qry);
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body onload="initialize();">
    <div id="map_div"></div>

    <div>
        <h3>Region</h3> 
        <select id="ddRegion" style="width: 150px;" onchange="refreshFusion();">
            <option value="">All</option>
            <option value="Middle East">Middle East</option>
            <option value="Red Sea">Red Sea</option>
            <option value="East Mediterranean">East Mediterranean</option>
            <option value="West Mediterranean">West Mediterranean</option>
            <option value="Adriatic">Adriatic</option>
            <option value="Black Sea">Black Sea</option>
            <option value="North Africa">North Africa</option>
            <option value="Indian Sub-Continent">Indian Sub-Continent</option>
        </select>
        <h3>Type</h3> 
        <select id="ddType" style="width: 150px;" onchange="refreshFusion();">
            <option value="">All</option>
            <option value="Shipping">Shipping</option>
            <option value="ICD">ICD</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Fusion Table: [Link](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?snapid=S366719I4RD)

Here is the Live Code: [Link](http://shapariya.com/fusionMap.html)

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also want to change the SELECT clause in your query to the following:

```
"SELECT PortName FROM " + tableid;
```

since only the location column should be in the SELECT clause of a Fusion Tables Layer query.

In general, you might want to consider using the new Fusion Tables Layer syntax as well. An example can be seen here:

http://code.google.com/apis/fusiontables/docs/samples/change_query.html

Comment: Thanks for the reference! It helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Line 37, you say type != '', I think you mean to test region != 'All' here.
Line 40, you have filters.lenght, you should have filters.length

If you use Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools, it makes it super easy to walk through code and see what values are set when.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. I've been introducing myself to Firebug but haven't been able to use it's full potential. This one helped to solve the problem as well. Thank you so much!